# change some columns to rows, but keep the rest the same

Tags: transpose, partial

My data looks like this,

```
Name   Col1    Data1   Date1   Data2   Date2   Data3   Date3
xxx     y         y   2/1/20      5    2/2/20    p   2/3/20
ppp     z         d   2/1/20      7    2/2/20    j   2/3/20
```

for multiple rows.

I need to change it to this

```
Name   Col1    Data   Date   
xxx     y         y   2/1/20    
ppp     z         d   2/1/20     
xxx     y         5   2/2/20   
ppp     z         7   2/2/20   
xxx     y         p   2/3/20   
ppp     z         j   2/3/20
```

I tried transpose, but it converts everything to columns. I want to kinda do a partial transpose - transpose only some columns. I am using Google sheets and don't know how to code.
Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Would be great if you could give us some contraints, like which languages/tools do you have access to, so that we can help you in a useful way to you.

Comment: just using Google sheets and google formulas. I do not have knowledge of SQL or VBA. I was hoping there could be a formula to do this, but am open to adding a script is needed.